# Does $\mbox{Hom}(\bullet,A)$ functor preserves pullbacks?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I know that $\mbox{Hom}(A,\bullet)$ functor preserves pullback ([Hom-functor preserves pullbacks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598274/hom-functor-preserves-pullbacks)) but what could we say about the contravariant functor  $\mbox{Hom}(\bullet,A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by that. It preserves limits (in particular pullbacks) as a functor $\mathcal{A}^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$. But this means as a contravariant functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathsf{Set}$ it sends colimits to limits (in particular pushouts to pullbacks).

(here $\mathcal{A}$ is your ambient category)

Comment: So pullbacks become pushouts?

Comment: @user84976 No. In general, you cannot say anything about what happens to limits in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Sorry, so pushouts become pullbacks?

Comment: @user84976 Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!